# Bipolar Junction Transistor

Tags: transistors, bjt

I am struggling with a question(ideal npn) where there is only one resistor Re. Where and how do I start with this question?
Vbb=10V
Vcc=20V
Re=10kOhm
The Question states : determine the terminal voltages of the transistor in the circuit with respect to ground. 
Also determine Vce. Vbe and Vcb[image]

Comment: On your edit, What question is being asked about this circuit? Which nodes are being considered as input and output?

Comment: Well. with a Vbb and a known Vbe (you should be given this), you know what Ve is. With a know Re you then know what Ie is. From the beta of the device you know what Ib is and thus what Ic is

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: Noted @Dave Tweed

Comment: Dave is right that many people here will not perform homework for you, at all. Others will offer varying degrees of help, depending on other factors. Not everyone agrees about how far is too far. Personally? I don't care. If I give you a complete answer and you cheat yourself, that's your problem. Others who read might benefit and I think these broader goals are equally important. I see you've added an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
I assumed HFE to be 100
Let me konw if I made any mistakes 
Thank you

Comment: @Phillip \$I_\text{E}\$ looks correct. \$I_\text{B}\$ looks correct. \$I_\text{C}\$ looks correct. Clearly, you know the BJT terminal voltages. And from those, I'm sure you can compute the relative node to node voltages, too.

Comment: Don't forget about SigFigs.  When using 1 sigfig for Vbe=0.7 then 2 sigfigs for Ie but don't show 6 sigfigs for Ic. Then you are implying an accuracy that is untrue.  So 930uA is OK when actual values for Ic and Ie are in my simulation.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Ah. But perhaps \$V_\text{BE}=0.700000000\$ and the OP just didn't write all that down. But good point, too. The OP should also state at the outset what the requirements are regarding stated precision. (Which gets to the instruments being used to make measurements and the concept of experimental replicability and objectivity.)

Comment: If we make assumptions for ideal, we must never forget tolerances or significant figures , so "ideal" is just  an approximation.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Also, don't forget that there doesn't appear to be an objective reality anymore. See: [Experimental rejection of observer-independence in the quantum world](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.05080.pdf) (2019).

Comment: @jonk Yes some of we observers have different realities from historical experiences because quantum events rarely affect the outcome in simple electronics but other assumptions with no specs often do result in differences of analog opinions. e.g. EMI.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is a simulation.  Can you figure out how these results work out from what you have been taught?

If not what do you need to learn?

Comment: One question. How did you determine hFE? Is it standard 100 for an ideal transistor?

Comment: It is never constant and may have only 10% of this when used as a switch and have a 3:1 max:min ratio, so for 1st order approximation 100 is common. Better suppliers have bins graded within part suffix.  However for this question they might assume Vbe=0.6V to make it simple. If it was Re=1K with 10mA you might see Vbe=0.7V So your answer if Ve=9.4V would be acceptable within tolerances.

Comment: hFE (or sometimes labelled as \$\beta\$ ) is typically given from the specs.... A lot of the times it is 100. You'll have to double check with your instructor.

Comment: I have seen this question in previous exam papers with beta unknown . Just wondering if the ideal npn means beta =100

Comment: The simple model regardless of beta is  Vbe= 700 mV. and when saturated Vce = 100mV but you will learn this varies with current and temperature and device specs. then when saturated, specs most often use Ic/Ib=10

Comment: @Phillip It means the exam paper makers already assume that unless it's written somewhere, you have understand and assume it yourself for typical ideal bjt, the beta of 100 is used.

Comment: Also realize those numbers I gave above (Vbe=700mV), there is really only 1 significant figure not 3

Comment: Thank you guys. Have been struggling for more that 2days on this simple question. Will post my answers

Answer (score 0):

β = 100 is a *typical* value, not an ideal value.

To me, an "ideal" BJT would be one whose B-E junction is an ideal diode (shorted when forward biased, open when reverse biased), and whose β is infinite.

Can you work out the answers to the question on that basis?

Comment: Then to U of C, ideal is a lot more complicated http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/ecen3320/newbook/chapter5/ch5_3.htm

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I pretty much agree with your reference about an ideal BJT and would assume that's what's meant unless over-riding English or specific equations or expressions carefully stated otherwise.